# JComboBox with DefaultComboBoxModel doesn't allow to add or remove

Tags: java, swing, model, autocomplete, jcombobox

This is my first post and I think I am doing it right.

I have a program that takes the user input from a AutoComplete jComboBox and then send's the input to be stored into a text file.(AutoComplete is done using the library glazedlists_java15/1.8.0).

**After using the Autocomplet feature I had to set the jComboBox to DefaultComboBoxModel.**

When the user presses the **Enter key**, the **jComboBox should update the list with the new Item typed from the keyboard**, so the user **can see the last typed item** in the jComboBox list.

**This** is done by **removing all the items from the jComboBox** and **then inserting them again** .

The problem is that **before** having the **AutoComplete** feature I could just say **jComboBox1.removeAllItems();** but now because of the model I have to do it with  **model.removeAllElements();**

```
public class Test {
    final static DefaultComboBoxModel model = new DefaultComboBoxModel();
    static JComboBox c                = new JComboBox(model);
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private static JButton b = new JButton();
    static JFrame f = new JFrame();
    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void TestFrame() {
        String[] a = {"hi1" , "hi2", "hi3", "hi4","hi5"};
        AutoCompleteSupport support = AutoCompleteSupport.install(c,
                GlazedLists.eventListOf(a));
        JPanel test = new JPanel();
        test.add(b);
        test.add(c);
        model.addElement(a);
        b.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                model.removeAllElements();

            }



        });
        f.add(test);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setVisible(true);
        f.setSize(500,500);

    }
```

The problem is that **model.removeAllElements();** and **model.addElement(s);** is not working so I can not update the jComboBox. Can you please take your time and help me find a solution. Thanks!

Comment: 1. no idea whats goal, then nor how could be done with GlazeList, 2. add DocumentListener to the derived Editor, 3. is there JComboBox#setEditable(true), and another 3-4 question based on == for better help sooner post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)

Comment: you tried it out with repaint(), validate() etc?

Comment: Cross-posted [here](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/comp.lang.java.programmer/lEqmO359MEk/discussion).

Comment: I tried to repaint() and validate() but still the same problem.

Answer (score 2):

Edit:

I don´t know where your problem is, this is totally working for me

```
final DefaultComboBoxModel model = new DefaultComboBoxModel();
JComboBox c                = new JComboBox(model);
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private JButton b = new JButton();

public TestFrame() {
    JPanel test = new JPanel();
    test.add(b);
    test.add(c);
    model.addElement("hi");

    b.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            model.removeAllElements();

        }
    });
    this.add(test);
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    this.setVisible(true);
    this.setSize(500,500);

}
```

maybe you don´t reach your keylistener

Comment: I will try with your example to see if is working then I will add the library to see if this is changing something. Thanks for your help

Comment: I tried your example and is working. Thanks again. I added the GlazedList library to your example and is not working anymore.

Comment: I edited the code from my question with the new tested code based on your example so you can take a look if you have time...

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

import ca.odell.glazedlists.EventList;
import ca.odell.glazedlists.GlazedLists;
import ca.odell.glazedlists.swing.AutoCompleteSupport;

public class TestFrame
{
    private static JComboBox c = new JComboBox();
    private static JButton b = new JButton();
    private static JFrame f = new JFrame();
    private static String[] a = {"hi1", "hi2", "hi3", "hi4", "hi5"};

    public static void TestFrame()
    {
        final EventList<String> items = GlazedLists.eventListOf(a);
        AutoCompleteSupport.install(c, items);
        JPanel test = new JPanel();
        test.add(b);
        test.add(c);
        c.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                c = (JComboBox) e.getSource();

                if (e.getActionCommand().equals("comboBoxEdited"))
                {
                    items.clear();
                }
            }
        });
        b.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                items.clear();
            }
        });
        f.add(test);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setVisible(true);
        f.setSize(500, 500);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                TestFrame();
            }
        });
    }
}
```